# How can I run code when event is scheduled in embedded Calendly widget in React Native Web View?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, postmessage, react-native-webview, calendly

I am trying to embed calendly widget into a react native application. The embedding is done and the code works with booking the event functionality also working. However, I am trying to listen the events emitted by the widget, without any success.

This is what my component code looks like.
I am trying to use the postMessage method both from the injectedJavascript prop and from the static html that I have, but it's not working at any point.

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react"
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native"
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview"


function isCalendlyEvent(e) {
    return e.data.event &&
        e.data.event.indexOf("calendly") === 0
}

const BookAppointment = ({ navigation }) => {
    const webViewRef = useRef(null)
    const source = {
        html: `
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        </head>
    <div class="calendly-inline-widget" style="min-width:320px;height:100%;" data-auto-load="false" id="myHeader">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js"></script>
    <script>
                  Calendly.initInlineWidget({
                  "parentElement": document.getElementById('myHeader'),
                    "url": 'https://calendly.com/taranathchimbili/doctor-appointment',
                    "prefill": {
                      "name": "John Doe",
                      "email": "john@doe2.com",
                    }
                  });
                  
                  window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage({"some": "something"});
                  window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
                  window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(event);
                  });
                  true;
    </script>`
    }
    const onMessage = (event) => {
        console.log("event", event)
    }
    
    return (
        <WebView
                injectedJavaScriptForMainFrameOnly={true}
                ref={(ref) => (webViewRef.current = ref)}
                originWhitelist={["*"]}
                source={source}
                startInLoadingState={true}
                renderLoading={() => <Loading text={"Loading..."} />}
                onMessage={onMessage}
                injectedJavaScript='
                window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
              window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(event);
           });
          true;
         '
            />
    )

export default BookAppointment
```

These are the reference links -

1. [How can I run code when event is scheduled in embedded Calendly widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64223129/how-can-i-run-code-when-event-is-scheduled-in-embedded-calendly-widget)
2. https://developer.calendly.com/api-docs/ZG9jOjI3ODM2MTAz-notifying-the-parent-window

Answer (score 0):

The postMessage method only accepts strings:
`window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify(event.data));`